# How to convert widget canvas (texture) to .png without saving it?

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I want to be able to do this:

```
#Reference widget
my_widget = self.ids.my_widget_kv
#Extract texture or graphics
drawing = my_widget.texture (or something that works)

#TODO convert to drawing .png in binary

#TODO edit in PIL
```

## TODO save or attach to email

At the moment I get my_widget.texture as None, and my_widget.canvas as canvas object.

I want to extract widgets looks as is and convert it to .png to attach to email or edit.

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
self.ids.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
```

This code saves drawing_zone looks to storage. I can't edit it in some in between steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just open and read the PNG file you'll get the bytes which you can then manipulate to your liking.

```
canvas_png = open("IMG.png","r+b").read()
canvas_data = (canvas_png.getvalue())

print(canvas_data)
```

You should see the 'binary' you need stored in this variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to skip the save part and convert it to .png in memory to use it immediately. export_to_png calls some widget methods that throw errors if i call them directly.

Comment: There is a way of storing it in memory (I think it's a python method). I will have a look for you when I get a chance. 

Any reason why you can't store it? It should store in the variable (memory anyway)